# Need help reverse engineering an algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, arrays, reverse, encryption

Im stuck reverse engineering a piece of java code. I was wondering if someone could help me out!

```
String var1 = "hello";
String var2 = "123456";

long var_l = 0L;
byte[] a1 = new byte[50];
byte[] a2 = new byte[50];

// i believe this checks if its between a-Z?
for (int j = 0; j < var1.length(); j++)
{
    a2[j] = (byte) var1.charAt(j);

    if ((a2[j] < 65) || (a2[j] > 122)
    {
        continue;
    } 

    var_l += 145 + a2[j];
}
```

The next part i really dont understand

```
var_l *= a1[0]; // a1 is a byte array of var2
var_l = 0xFFFF & var_l * (0xFF & var_l);

if (var_l < 100L)
{
    var_l = 2728L;
}
```

Could someone please help me out here? Im trying to learn cyphering algorithms here but im having trouble following the logic.

Here is the full code:

param_licensekey & licensename & lictype are global vars. Please read my comment below about the reason why im reverse engineering this. Thanks for all the awnsers.

```
public boolean check_license()
  {
    long l = 0L;
    byte[] arrayOfByte2 = new byte['ÿ'];
    byte[] arrayOfByte1 = new byte['ÿ'];
    int i;
    if (this.param_licensename.length() >= 2)
    {
      if (this.param_licensekey.length() >= 2)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.param_licensekey.length(); j++)
          arrayOfByte1[j] = (byte)this.param_licensekey.charAt(j);
        for (j = 0; j < this.param_licensename.length(); j++)
        {
          arrayOfByte2[j] = (byte)this.param_licensename.charAt(j);
          if ((this.param_licensename.charAt(j) < 'A') || (this.param_licensename.charAt(j) > 'Z'))
            continue;
          arrayOfByte2[j] = (byte)(32 + arrayOfByte2[j]);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < this.param_licensename.length(); j++)
        {
          if ((arrayOfByte2[j] < 65) || (arrayOfByte2[j] > 122))
            continue;
          l += 145 + arrayOfByte2[j];
        }
        l *= arrayOfByte1[0];
        l = 0xFFFF & l * (0xFF & l);
        if (l < 100L)
          l = 2728L;
        String str = this.param_licensekey.charAt(0) + l;
        if (!this.param_licensekey.startsWith(str))
        {
          this.lictype = -1;
          i = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          this.lictype = (i[0] - 48);
          i = 1;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        i = 0;
      }
    }
    else
      i = 0;
    return i;
  }
```

Comment: For reference, this looks like the work of someone who's trying to write C'ish code in Java.

Comment: It could also be the result of a decompiler.

Comment: It'd seem to me that a decompiler wouldn't be able to arbitrarily use arrays like this code does.  Even if the stuff were inlined, it'd still be quite a stretch.

Comment: This looks like some very stupid hash function to me.

Comment: Hi guys, this is the work of Java Decompiler. It did a pretty good job in getting the source code. Im still trying to figure it out. Ill post the entire function. Keep in mind that im not using this for illegal purposes but for study material. Its a decompiled jar from my teacher and there could be questions about it on the exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// var_l = var_l * a1[0]
var_l *= a1[0]; // a1 is a byte array of var2

// The low 16 bits of var_l are multipled by the low 8 bits of var_l (the parenthesis
// are not necessary in this case).
var_l = 0xFFFF & var_l * (0xFF & var_l);

// Self explanatory
if (var_l < 100L) {
 var_l = 2728L;
}
```

Comment: The "self explanatory" part is still a bit interesting. The 2728L hard code may be some sort of a bit mask. In binary that's 101010101000. Which does look to be a pattern of sorts on the bits. It'd be interesting to know how var_1 is used downstream of this.